# Eclipse Rich Client Platform - Cross Platfrom Development

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have started an Eclipse RCP project on OSX and was hoping to continue development using windows 10, but when I imported the project into windows all of the SWT imports in the code were showing errors, I have tried to downloaded org.eclipse.swt as a project into eclipse and import it into all other projects, but when I try to run the application I get the following exception:

*java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)*

I also noticed that when I attempt to run the project it bootloader is defined for osx, not windows as follow:

*BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IE*

I was wondering if someone would have any suggestions on how to go about cross platform development in Eclipse RCP?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse#Multi-platform_builds

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Maven, defining a specific profile for each platform.
You can try the following pom definition (this is just for SWT),adapting it to your application (changing something and adding your dependencies) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>yourGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>YourArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <swt.version>SWT_Version</swt.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-eclipse-repo</id>
            <url>http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          ....//your dependencies
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>win32-x86</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
                    <version>${swt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>win32-x86-64</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</artifactId>
                    <version>${swt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86</artifactId>
                    <version>${swt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86-64</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
                    <version>${swt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-x86-64</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
                    <version>${swt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I hope this helps! ;)